# How remove duplicates of tuples in a list, where the tuple elements are in reverse order?

Tags: python, duplicates, tuples

I am working on a assignment where my program shall ask the  user about a positive integer *n* which the prgogram will found the positive integers a and b, satsifying *a*^3 + *b*^3 = *n*.

My work and progress thus far is shown below

```
def ramunajan(n):
    list=[]
    u = int(n**(1/3)+1)
    for a in range (0,u):
        b = (n-a**3)**(1/3)
        b = round(b)
        if a**3+b**3 == n:
            list.append((a,b))
    return list     

while True:
    try:
        n = input("För vilket positivt heltal n vill du hitta a och b där a^3 + b^3 = n ?\n")
    except ValueError or n <= 0:
            continue
    else:
            break

list_1 = ramunajan(int(n))
print (list_1)
```

(The input text message is in swedish.)

My problem now is that when a user types in, eg 1729, the program gives output accordingly

> > > For what postivie integer n would you like to find a and b, satisfying a^3 + b^3 = n ?
> > >
> > > 1729
> > >
> > > [(1, 12), (9, 10), (10, 9), (12, 1)]

How do I get rid of the reverse duplicates, ie (10, 9) and (12, 1), from the list?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

replace `u = int(n**(1/3)+1)` with `u = int((n**(1/3))/2) + 1`

so it checks only the first half of the pool, since the second half are duplicates